# Navigation url with new Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

What is an URL to open navigation from current user location to eg. London?

Based on [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) I tried doing it in that way:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&dir_action=navigate=London
but it's certainly not working, while trying same url with any different parameter eg. destination: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=London works pretty well.

So what am I doing wrong or perhaps should I place "dir_action=navigate" somewhere else?